# Automatically running a file, not program, using Windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-10

I read this, and did this: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7

But it didn't work for my intention: I want to run a file, not a program, at a specific time everyday.

I want to open a .docx-document using MS-Word, when the task runs.

Does this not work on Windows? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: What is the extension of the file you want to run? Do you have an error message to provide us? Did you try to run the same command line inside a command prompt?

Comment: @Luke It's just docx. I just want to open it at given time. No error message. It's just that it does not open at that specified time. What command line should I write?

Comment: Consider including a short on what you actually set up. Does the task run as the user for whom the file should open? Is the user logged in at the specified time? What happens if you run the task manually and what is the last execution status/result of the task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In the **Action** tab click **New** or **Edit**.
2. As Action, choose **Start a program**.
3. In the **Program/Script** enter the full path of the Winword executable.
   For instance in my case: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE"
4. In the **Add arguments** field enter the full path of your .docx document.
5. To test the scheduled task right now without having to wait, you can right click it and select **Run**

Comment: Amazing. Just amazing. I will upvote you when I get 15 reputations.

Comment: You are welcome. You can still take the good habit to vote, even if it doesn't update the number for the moment. It is still partially taken into account.

Comment: Do I need to quote the path of document in the arguments field?

Comment: @DavidH.J. probably not if there is not space in your path.